# Is serializability same as sequential consistency?

Tags: serializable, consistency

I have found people answering differences between linearizability and searializability, but nowhere have I found people either saying that serializability is same as sequential consistency or it is different from that.

Also I have been pounded with different definitions of the above terms in different articles, books and web pages and I have confused it all.
Could someone please explain the difference between serializability and sequential consistency is it exists.

I would appreciate formal definitions of the above terms additionally if possible (both in plain English and in terms of the program or execution histories).

Comment: I think they are same. This blog https://irenezhang.net/blog/2015/02/01/consistency.html also confirms that.

Comment: Serializability is about isolation, sequential consistency (as the name implies) is about consistency.

Answer (score 7):

Serializability is more strict than Sequential consistency.

The definition of **Sequential consistency** in wiki: 
The result of any execution is the same as if the **operations** of all the processors were executed in some sequential order, and the operations of each individual processor appear in this sequence in the order specified by its program.

And, the definition of **Serializability** in wiki:
A transaction schedule is serializable if its outcome (e.g., the resulting database state) is equal to the outcome of its **transactions** executed serially, i.e. without overlapping in time.

So, the granularity of Sequential consistency is a single operation (e.g., read or write), while that of Serializability is a transaction (i.e., a sequence of operations).

In other words, if a program satisfies serializablity, it also satisfies sequential consistency, and not vice versa.

Comment: How would `Serializability` differ from `Sequential consistency with Multi-Object Operations` (mentioned in this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1281621)